Como evaluar si mi servidor SQL Server esta disponible
Estoy programando en Xamarin forms en Visual Studio 2019, y estoy tratando de controlar si mi servidor es accesible cuando tumbamos el Wifi donde se encuentra alojado el mismo, hice una función que me evalúa si puedo abrir la conexión de SQL Server,pero aunque el Wifi esté desconectada me devuelve que el servidor está disponible cosa que no es cierto.
A continuación muestro el método y la cadena de conexión:
public static bool verificar(string cadena)
{ 
  try
  {
     (using var conexion = new sqlconnection(cadena)) 
     conexion.open();
     return true;
  }
  catch(sqlException)
  {
    return false;
  }
}

Si me pudieran colaborar se lo agradecería, saludos de antemano.

Hola. Pon el código como texto pulsando en [edit].
